# Error importing _counter form pycrypto library

Tags: python, pycrypto

This line in `Crypto/Util/Counter.py` from the pycrypto lib:

```
from Crypto.Util import _counter
```

Causes this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _counter
```

But I have the file `_counter.so` under `Crypto/Util` in the pycrypto library of Python's site-packages. I am using Python 2.7.5, 32-bit for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File _counter.so belongs to Linux/MacOS package, Windows should have _counter.pyd instead. Prebuilt Windows PyCrypto packages can be downloaded from here: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

Comment: Awesome :) That resolved the long lasting issue. Thanks @Maciej Malycha